# FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen not working in flutter web

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I am using Firebase messaging for Firebase push notifications with `firebase_messaging: ^14.7.9` which is the latest version. I know `onBackgroundMessage` and `onMessageOpenedApp` don't work in Flutter Web. But I read in any documentation that `onMessage` works fine in Flutter web. But it's also not working.
onMessage listener of index.html works and prints the console message. But on the dart side `onMessage` not working. Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.
I have initialized Flutter Web correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Web Firebase Push Notification received twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77746111/flutter-web-firebase-push-notification-received-twice)

Answer (score 0):

First of all add firebase_core and firebase_messaging to your pubspec.yaml

In your main() function add the init Firebase

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxx"));
```

After initializing Firebase you have to initialize Firebase messaging and ask for Notifications in the Browser, which you do like this

```
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.getNotificationSettings();
```

Add this in a javascript file

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('Received background message ', payload);

    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
      };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Add this to your index.html file

```
<script>
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
      });
  }
</script>
```

Then you are basically good to go, that is all you have to do. Then go to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/your-project-id/messaging and add your flutter web app to it, and send a test notification to your application by getting the token from your application by using await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();